# pageY of scrolled element from mouseenter event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a long, scrollable list in an absolutely positioned container in the middle of my page (I do know how far the container is offset from the top of the screen, and the overflow is hidden on all the key elements). Each `li` in the list has a mouseover event. The events I see have a pageY in it, but that's the mouse position, and thus varies if I enter the `li` from above vs below. I need a constant value to position something alongside.

I looked in the `srcElement` property but the `offsetTop` within that is several 1000s, which means it is not based on the viewable content but the scrolled content.

How can I get a constant value of a scrolled `div` *relative to the window* as whole?

Note I canNOT easily run other DOM requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offsetTop` you mentioned and substract the current scrollYOffset which you can get using `window.pageYOffset`.

```
var y = srcElement.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's going to help. I may have been to brief in the my explanation of the problem, and have tried to add some stuff